# Looking for two synonyms for success/failure which rhyme

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, antonyms, rhymes

I’m looking for two words with the following conditions:

1. Word A is a synonym of “success” (or is the word “success”).
2. Word B is a synonym of “failure” (or is the word “failure”).
3. Words A and B rhyme.
4. Words A and B are antonyms (note: you can probably ignore this requirement since I’m pretty sure condition 1 & 2 all but guarantee this condition.)

---

It might be easier to explain with a hypothetical example… imagine the English language contained the word:

> Pizaster | Noun
>
> - great success

We could then have the solution “Pizaster/Disaster” since they satisfy all 4 conditions: Pizaster means success, disaster means failure, they both rhyme, they are both antonyms.

Unfortunately (or rather fortunately) I can’t just add words to the English language like this, so I’m looking for an existing pair of words that actually exist.

If there’s nothing that’s a perfect synonym for success/failure but still captures the same essence of good/bad, I’ll still accept it as an answer. Also the final solution could totally have the word “success” or “failure” in it as well (e.g. if there is already a word which means failure and rhymes with success, then we could have the solution success + this word you’re thinking of)

Answer (score 0):

Lacking the mental agility or vocabulary to find a solution in the head, it is a simple matter to look mechanically for synonyms. As is often the case with "synonyms" (or near-synonyms), each is only truly synonymous in certain contexts, so the rhyming doublets are not convincing or immediately perceptible as success/failure.

Nevertheless, here is one set:

> [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/success)

[image]

I note the success/nonsuccess doublet only for completeness; it is ploddingly obvious and has no charm or rhythmic force.

Answer (score 0):

I feel both context and flow of the storytelling are critical here.

> I wanted success but I had to confess

> I had success that I had to suppress

> After my success all I could do was regress

Answer (score 0):

I will try, though some may be more metaphors than synonyms of success and failure.

| success | failure |
| --- | --- |
| progress/success | regress |
| perfection | abjection/imperfection |
| ascent | descent |
| feat | defeat |

My favourite pair is ***feat and defeat.***